# Swift: Cant get progress of URLSessionDownload in delegate?

Tags: swift, swift3, download, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Ok, I have never saved files before (m4as in this case) and have no idea if I am doing this correctly and moreover cannot get the download progress of the URL, despite including the required URLSessionDownloadDelegate funcs here:

```
 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            print("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("Download finished: \(location)")
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("Task completed: \(task), error: \(error)")
    }
```

I got these off a tutorial however nothing is printed to console ever. I tried calling these functions however I do not know where to get the downloadTask var or the session.

This is how I download my file, this works:

```
func goDownload()
    {
        if let audioUrl = testUrl { //set at beginning

            // then lets create your document folder url
            let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

            // lets create your destination file url
            let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
            print(destinationUrl)

            // to check if it exists before downloading it
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
                print("********** The file already exists at path")

                // if the file doesn't exist
            } else {
                // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                    guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                    do {
                        // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)

                        //success
                        print("************** SUCCESS File moved to documents folder", audioUrl)
                        self.playModeStreaming = false

                        self.pausePlay()
                        AudioPlayerManager.shared.play(url: audioUrl)

                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }).resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

However even if I try to get the downloadTask from here I have type issues. How can I get the download progress (bytes received, etc) using this download func?

EDIT: This is what I have:

```
 var session = URLSession()
    let sessDelegate = CustomDelegate()
self.session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: sessDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
```

then replaced URLSession.shared with `session` in the above func.

My custom delegate class separately:

```
class CustomDelegate : NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    //define all  `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` and `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` methods here
    //URLSessionDelegate methods

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            print("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("Download finished: \(location)")
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: location)
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("Task completed: \(task), error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting delegate as self. Rather you should instantiate an instance of your CustomDelegate class and set it as delegate of your 'self.session'

Comment: I did. Here Ill update my question, I didn't update that part

Comment: Whats wrong?  is it with my download func?

Comment: Are you calling session.resume() ?

Comment: Yes. Look at the download func it is right there.

Comment: can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom delegate class, and implement `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` and `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` protocols.

```
class CustomDelegate : NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {

//define all  `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` and `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` methods here

}
```

Now create an instance of above class like so :

```
let myCustomDelegate = CustomDelegate();
```

You will then need to set the delegate property of your `NSURLSession` instance like so :

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:myCustomDelegate delegateQueue:nil];
```

**SWIFT 3**

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: myCustomDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Ref Links:

1. [NSURLSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession/sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:)
2. [From NSURLConnection to NSURLSession](http://From%20NSURLConnection%20to%20NSURLSession)

Comment: Can you please answer with Swift, Im new to this

Comment: Can you write out the code in Swift. 2nd link does not work

Comment: For Swift 2.0 code you can try 'NSURLSession' instead of 'URLSession'

Comment: Ok, I did this thanks but the functions are still not being called.

Comment: Never mind. Ok I did that and set that delegate in my session. Still nothing. See my edit

Comment: You can declare delegate class anywhere.  You should review documentation for defining protocols.

Comment: Please look at my edit, it is all running and set up exactly as described in documentation. It is still not printing within those funcs